# How to check if a user has logged in to a Google account in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am developing a small iOS application on Swift, and I use google sign in sdk to sign in. When a user clicks on the enter button, he should transfer to another view if successful, I don’t know how to check whether the user entered or canceled the input, thanks in advance.

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try below code,

```
if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser != nil) {
    //logged in
} else {
    //not logged in
}
```

Hope this works for you!